# Object removes itself from its container

Tags: .net, oop

What's a good OOP way?

Now I have every object containing a reference to its container as well as a copy of its key or index to identify itself in that container. the DeleteMe() method calls the container's Delete(key) method. I think this is bad because of the tight coupling, cyclic references and the duplicate copy of the key/index.

The reason I want to do this is because each object is represented in the UI and has a context menu generated by itself, with options like "Delete" and "Rename".

I heard that delegates or events can be used here, but I don't really understand the motivation behind them and if they're just YAGNI for me.

Comment: A good way?  Not sure.  But it sounds like an opportunity to abuse [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally Delete, Rename operations should not belong to Objects, these should belong only to container.

> > The reason I want to do this is because each object is represented in the UI and has a context menu generated by itself, with options like "Delete" and "Rename"

Still operations on container should be invoked like

```
  container.Delete(Object)
  container.Rename(Object, String newName)
```

By creating DeleteMe, Rename on the object itself, you are creating object dependent on the container, and then it cannot be used to be stored in other container like List, Dictionary, etc ( or DeleteMe will fail)

Now for the requirement that Delete Handler should delete the object from the container, you can use [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). For example

```
DeleteCommand command = new DeleteCommand(); // Create new Command 
CommandManager.Register(command); // Create CommandManager class that will have mechanism of registering command, and has reference to object container. method is something like command.Set(Object container)
command.Execute(this); // pass instance as parameter, and in the Execute it will be similar to container.Remove(parameter);
```

The above code is just outline, you can customize according to the requirements. Other actions (like Rename) can be added similarly.

Comment: +1 for Delete/Rename etc do not belong to the object, but to some kind of system or container that uses those objects. Just as a filesystem is responsible for managing files, and files do not "delete themselves".

Comment: Can you clarify your command pattern example? The last line is in the context menu handler in the object being deleted? Where does it get it's command object from?

Comment: Also, deleting according to a reference seems like it requires an O(N) search. I prefer to use an index or dictionary key.

Comment: Command object can be created in the click/double click event (in WinForms, In WPF, commmand infrastructure is already built). You need to look/study [command design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) a bit. But they will make the design loosely coupled, and it pays off in long term

Deleting -> you can define Delete(Key ) in container, then can call container.Delete(obj.Key) from within Delete method.

Comment: Can you confirm my understanding?

An instance of DeleteCommand is created when the UI control is created/refreshed.

The DeleteCommand object contains a pointer to the container, a copy of the key, and an Execute() method which calls container.Remove(key).

The DeleteCommand object is stored in the object that might get deleted and stays there until its associated control is refreshed (which happens on any change).

The click handler for Delete is a member function of the the object being deleted and calls .Execute(). @Tilak

Comment: Yes this can be one way. Only thing is There should be CommandManager, that will provide reference of container to DeleteCommand. container reference will never be present in the reference. There can be other ways. But your way if fine too.

Comment: I am not talking about WPF CommandManager. Its something that you have to create (may be with different name if you like). It will be [singleton](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton). You will register your container with CommandManager. When Command will call Register on CommandManager singleton instance, commandmanager will associate container to command